# Excel VBA - If a cell in column B contains a value then column A equals "value" BUT do not overwrite existing column A data

Tags: vba, excel

The title of the question might be a little confusing but essentially what I am trying to do is write a value to column A if Column B is not empty. This must be repeated for C through Q. The code I have now produces the desired result IF there is value in the B column. However, if there is no value for B then my replacement text will fill in all sorts of blank cells outside of the target range of A1:A. Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=If(B1<>"""",""NEW VALUE"","""")"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VBA so please forgive any vagueness in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will only work if A1 is the first blank.

```
.Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=If(B1<>"""",""NEW VALUE"","""")"
```

`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` may be a discontiguous range of areas that may or may not start in row 1. You need to convert it to an xlR1C1 style formula in order to have it correctly identify the first blank row.

```
.Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""NEW VALUE"", TEXT(,))"
```

`TEXT(,)` is the same as `""` and you do not have to double-up the quotes within a quoted string; similarly, any positive number representing the length of a value in column B is the same as `<>""`.

Comment: Jeeped,

Thank you for the clarification on what exactly was wrong with the formula I was attempting to use. I am certain I will use what you taught me at some point in the future!

Comment: Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'The column must change to match the target column

        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""NEW VALUE"", TEXT(,))" 'RC# is the variable where # must equal the variable column from above
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting formulas and getting their values afterwards, you can do the same logic by using pure VBA:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If .Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
            .Cells(i, 1) = "NEW VALUE"
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tehscript, 

Thank you very much! Your solution worked perfectly!